# Trying to make php recognize file path as domain

Tags: php, html, css, path, directory

I am working on a image viewer. I want to have it where the images are stored at another domain instead of on that domain example regular domain name.com and then i want it to have (domain that stores images) dedi1-app.com how can I do this here is my code so far.

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'testimg/'; //image's folder path

$num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

$folder = opendir($folder_path);

if($num_files > 0)
{
 while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder)))
 {
  $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
  $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp')
  {
   ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  height="150" /></a>
            <?php
  }
 }
}
else
{
 echo "Your Vinx Library Is Empty!, Add some jazz!";
}
closedir($folder);
?>
```

Comment: The directory on the other domain must support directory listing (not restricted in .htaccess and does not have any files named index.html, index.php, home.html, home.php, default.html, default.php, etc.) http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Comment: What do you see when you point your browser to the image directory at the other domain?

Comment: This is an example of a directory that supports directory listing http://cowdd.com/wu/responses/

Comment: Sorry for late reply here is the error pendir(http://www.dedi1-vinx.pe.hu/img/): failed to open dir: not implemented

Answer (score 0):

Give `$folder_path` the URL of the location of the folder that contains the image in the other domain:

```
$folder_path = "http://www.otherdomain.com/images/";
```

Comment: @Stacky128 and what was the result?

Comment: If whats inside the `src=" "` is a valid url to an image, like for instance `<img src="http://www.google.com/somefolder/someimage.jpg">` then the image should appear.